# R: Looping over a vector of subsets of data, and for each, comparing it against some aggregates

Tags: r

Suppose I work with the toy data

```
library(dplyr)

dat <- data.frame(
ID = letters[1:20], 
Category = rep(c(1,2),10),
Values = rnorm(20,0,1)
)

A_B <- dat[1:6,]
A_notB <- dat[7:14,]
notA_B <- dat[15:16,]
notA_notB <- dat[17:20,]
```

For each subset, I want to compute its variance grouped by category, which I can do.  However, for each subset, I would also like to compare its variance grouped by category against three alternatives.

It's easiest to explain if I just work with the example of subset `A_B`.  I would like to compare its grouped variance against the grouped variances of each of the following:

(1) All the data not in `A_B`,

(2) all the data in a variable that begins with `notA` (so the union of `notA_B` and `notA_notB`),

(3) all the data that ends in `notB`

Is there a way to accomplish this in a for-loop, or are the three groupings of the data so dependent on the names of the subsets that just brute-force writing out the code for each case really the most efficient way to proceed?

Comment: Please add your expected output based on the sample data you provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build function splitting db to "case" versus rest and apply to list of different cases to see all the comparison of variances

```
  Case <- c("A_B", "A_notB", "notA_B", "notA_notB")

  Total <- rbind(cbind(A_B, gr="A_B"),
        cbind(A_notB, gr="A_notB"),
        cbind(notA_B, gr="notA_B"),
        cbind(notA_notB, gr="notA_notB"))

  vargr_comp <- function(case){
     Total%>%
      mutate(split = ifelse(gr==case, case, paste0("not ", case)))%>%
      group_by(split, gr, Category)%>%
      summarise(var=var(Values))
  }

  lapply(Case, vargr_comp)
```